# Any lightweight video editors for Ubuntu?

Tags: video, gui, ffmpeg

I need to do some simple video editing like attaching two videos together (like [this question](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/apoxkq/any_lightweight_video_editors_for_linux/)) which could be done by these commands :

```
echo file "./simplescreenrecorder-۲۰۲۱-۰۵-۱۵_۱۱.۳۴.۲۵.mp4" >  mylist.txt 
echo file "./simplescreenrecorder-۲۰۲۱-۰۵-۱۵_۱۴.۰۷.۴۹.mp4" >> mylist.txt

sudo chmod 755 mylist.txt


sudo ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

So if possible I would like to find some light video editor with GUI environment for this usage or if possible I like to ask, is there any online site or Ubuntu app to give above codes to it and create two input forms for getting the video path address and run above commands on them to create new attached video results Like the below Flowchart:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try [LosslessCut](https://mifi.github.io/lossless-cut/). It will allow, "Lossless merge/concatenation of arbitrary files (with identical codecs parameters, e.g. from the same camera)".

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to concatenate two videos. This indeed can be done with a simple, linear video editor. **Avidemux** will be very suited for this task. As with your `ffmpeg` command, it will allow you to concatenate two video files without transcoding, i.e., without any loss in quality. Just like for `ffmpeg`, this requires your video files to be the same format (same codecs, same resolution).

There is more you can do with Avidemux. You can cut out pieces of the video, demux and mux different media streams, and transcode to another format.

Avidemux unfortunatelly **is not available in the standard Ubuntu repositories for a long time**. It is also not available in the Ubuntu snapstore. Fortunatelly, it is available as [a stand-alone AppImage](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/download.html) and if you enable flatpak on your system, it can be conveniently installed as a flatpak as well.

*"Is there any online site or Ubuntu app to give above codes?"*

There might be, but I did not find any (I did not search).